# Drop or remove column using awk

Tags: unix, awk, split

I wanted to drop first 3 column;

This is my data;

```
DETAIL 02032017 

Name    Gender  State   School  Class
A          M    Melaka  SS  D
B          M    Johor   BB  E
C          F    Pahang  AA  F
EOF 3
```

I want my data like this:

```
DETAIL 02032017             
School  Class
SS       D
BB       E
AA       F
EOF 3
```

This is my current command that I get **mycommandoutput**:

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
{file="TEST_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv";  
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL"date"" ORS h ORS) $0 > file} END{for(file in a)     print "EOF " a[file] > file}' testing.csv
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you :)

*I want to remove first three column*

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the first three columns, you can just set them to empty strings, leaving alone those that don't *have* three columns, something like:

```
awk 'NF>=3 {$1=""; $2=""; $3=""; print; next}{print}'
```

That has the potentially annoying habit of still having the field separators between those empty fields but, since modifying columns will reformat the line anyway, I assume that's okay:

```
DETAIL 02032017
   School Class
   SS D
   BB E
   AA F
EOF 3
```

If `awk` is the only tool being used to process them, the spacing won't matter. If you *do* want to preserve formatting (meaning that the columns are at very specific locations on the line), you can just get a substring of the entire line:

```
awk '{if (NF>=3) {$0 = substr($0,25)}; print}'
```

Since that doesn't modify individual fields, it won't trigger a recalculation of the line that would change its format:

```
DETAIL 02032017
School Class
SS  D
BB  E
AA  F
EOF 3
```

Comment: Do you mean i need to do like this?  ---- **awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR>=1 {h=$0; next} {$1="";$2="";$3="";print}
{file="TEST_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv";  
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL"date"" ORS h ORS) $0 > file} END{for(file in a)     print "EOF " a[file] > file}' testing.csv**--@paxdiablo ? I cannot get it

Comment: @karakfa can u help me?